# Is there anything a table-level constraint declaration can do that a column-level one can not do?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, ddl

Had an exam today. One question disturbed me:

> What can a table-level constraint do that a column-level constraint can't do?

My answer was that only a table-level constraint declaration permits setting up a composite primary key. I guess this is not the only difference. How could I have added to that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've forgotten about other types of constraint than primary key (also applies to unique, check, and foreign key constraints) but that's basically it.

A column-level constraint can only reference the column that it is declared next to. A table-level constraint can reference multiple columns.

Comment: Hm, this is the SQL Server implementation, right? Postgres allows `create table a (t int not null, u int not null check (u > t+v), v int null );` for example. No idea what the standard says.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - yep, for SQL Server. I've no idea of what the standard says either (or how other DBMSs address this)